# Reed Solomon Error Detection Capability only guaranteed to be Error Correction Capability

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, finite-fields, coding-theory

I am setting up a Reed Solomon library to correct AND detect errors as the come in. For simplicity lets look at a Reed Solomon configuration where

- m(symbol size)    : 8 [GF(256)]
- k(user payload)   : 2
- 2T(parity symbols): 2

Yielding a transmitted payload of 4 octets.

This can correct any 1 symbol error and, the purpose of this post, it can DETECT 2 symbol errors. There is limited literature on the error detection of RS, however just for a cursary source you can check the introduction in the wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reed-Solomon_error_correction

By adding t check symbols to the data, a Reed–Solomon code can detect any combination of up to and including t erroneous symbols, or correct up to and including ⌊t/2⌋ symbols.

However this doesnt seem to match my observations.

I have a library, primarily built from https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Reed-Solomon_codes_for_coders which from what I can tell works very well. I set up a exhaustive test surrounding our implementation and found a case where there are 2 symbol errors (which from what I understood should be DETECTABLE) however it is not. From what I understand, a simple checok to see if an uncorrectable error occurred which passes the normal checks (i.e. the error locator is valid, find errors has a valid error count, polynomial degree is valid) is to recalculate the syndromes for the corrected message. If the syndromes are non zero then we still have an error. However when I do this the syndromes are all 0, suggesting no error is found and that we have a collision between an error vector with 1 erroneous symbol, and an error vector with 2 erroneous symbols.

This is the test:

```
# Create Message
msg_in = [0x10,0x2f]
# Append RS FEC codes
msg_enc = rs_encode_msg(msg_in)

# Apply Error
errVec = [0,0x2b,0,0xea]
for i,err in enumerate(errVec):
        msg[i] ^= err;

# Decode
# Syndromes
synd = rs_calc_syndromes(msg)
# Error Locator
err_loc = rs_find_error_locator(synd)
# Error Positions
pos = rs_find_errors(err_loc)
# Correct
msg = rs_correct_errata(msg, synd, pos, err_loc)

#Calculate syndromes again
newSynd = rs_calc_syndromes(msg)
```

Output:

```
Message
0x10 0x2f 

Encoded Message
0x10 0x2f 0x1 0x3e 

Encoded Message With Errors
0x10 0x4 0x1 0xd4

Syndromes
0xc1 0x46 
Error Locator
0x8 0x1
Error Position
0x00 # The first position

Corrected Message
0xd1 0x4 0x1 0xd4

Recalculated Syndromes
0x0 0x0
```

If you are still reading, thank you. I know I have no provided the entire library, but I did provide the inputs, and outputs, and key variable values. What I want to know is if my understanding written above is wrong; that we can DETECT 2T symbol errors where 2T is the amount of added symbols. Because from this test case it seems there is a collision, I test this further by just calculating the syndromes across the following error vectors which further supports a collision and that Reed Solomon CANNOT NECESSARILY DETECT ALL errors up to 2T. Let me know if I am wrong.

```
error vector: 0xc1 0x0 0x0 0x0
yielding syndrome: 0xc1 0x46
```

and

```
error vector: 0x0 0x2b 0x0 0xea
yielding syndrome: 0xc1 0x46
```

Has a collision

Comment: The minimum distance of this code is $d=3$, so it is natural that there are error patterns of weight two and weight one that yield identical syndromes. This is because there are valid codewords of weight three, and you can write such a vector as a sum of vectors of weights 2 and 1. In other words, some patterns of two errors also match the syndrome of a single error. Is that what you are worried about?

Comment: Yet in other words. There may be different expectations as to what it means for a code to be able to detect two errors. If you call a code a single-error-correcting and double-error-detecting only if it can tell the two cases apart, then I agree with you. That Wikipedia article is then simply wrong. The reason is that for a code to be able to do all that, its minimum Hamming distance should be at least four. But, the minimum distance of this code is three, so it cannot tell these two cases from each other.

Comment: In another context slightly different language is used. For example, a binary CRC code is said to detect all the error patterns of weight $t$, if the minimum weight of a non-zero codewords is $d_{min}\ge t+1$. There *detection* simply means that a CRC-check will raise a flag that this block of data is not a codeword. No attempts at error-correction are made.

Comment: Anyway, a code with minimum distance $d$ can correct $\lfloor(d-1)/2\rfloor$ errors and detect $\lfloor d/2\rfloor$ errors. **IF** we adopt the usual convention that detection includes the ability to tell that at least that many errors must have occurred. For there to be a difference between the correction/detection capabilities, the code must thus have an even minimum Hammiing distance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand now. It’s not: T symbols of error correction AND 2T symbols of error detection. It’s T symbols of error correction OR 2T symbols of error detection. T symbol errors have unique syndromes where 2T are not unique but are non zero. The uniqueness makes it correctable , the non zero makes it detectable. So you cannot both correct T errors and detect 2T because many (in this case about 4000) of the syndromes for T errors is also the syndrome for 2T, and there is no way to differentiate if you should try and correct for a single error, or if you should flag it as an uncorrectable error.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

In general, if $d\geq 2e+f+1,$ a code with minimum distance $d$ can correct $e$ and detect $f$ errors simultaneously.

The two extreme scenarios are when one chooses exclusively to

$$\textrm{detect}~~d-1$$ or to exclusively

$$\textrm{correct}~~\lfloor \frac{d-1}{2} \rfloor$$ errors.

Comment: I will be honest, I am not following this at all. When you talk about distance, what exactly are you referring to. Hamming distance is generally on a bit level, which is confusing when you apply that language to Reed Solomon which functions on a symbol level.  More over, what is d, 3, and f? Reed Solomon (in non errasure channels) can correct T symbol errors where 2T is the number of parity symbols added. I dont know what (d-1)/2 is. Can you try and explain it in a different way for the slow among us?

Comment: Reed Solomon codes symbols are in an extension field, say $GF(2^m)$ which can be represented as blocks of binary symbols. If $m=8,$ you can think of the symbols as bytes. The Hamming distance goes up by one, when two bytes in the same position are different. All the decoding takes place at byte level and errors are corrected bytewise. So this is NOT bit based hamming distance.